# cvlc command does not work after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, vlc

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.4 I cannot run vlc from a terminal. This is what happens:

```
$ ls 
MashaAndTheBearCompilation.mp4  NomadenDerLuefte.mp4
$ cvlc MashaAndTheBearCompilation.mp4
VLC media player 3.0.9.2 Vetinari (revision 3.0.9.2-0-gd4c1aefe4d)
```

I would very much appreciate any ideas about how to resolve this issue.
Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Can you try `cvlc -vv MashaAndTheBearCompilation.mp4`.

Comment: @andrew.46 it does not make any change, I still get the same result: `VLC media player 3.0.9.2 Vetinari (revision 3.0.9.2-0-gd4c1aefe4d)`

Comment: And after running: `sudo apt-get install vlc-bin` ?

Comment: @andrew.46 it was already installed so it did not make any change, `vlc-bin is already the newest version (3.0.9.2-1).`  I have also deleted the .config file. I am checking the log file and it reports: `-- logger module started --
main: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
main: playlist is empty
-- logger module stopped --`

Comment: @andrew.46 , thank you for the suggestions. I managed to solve the problem by doing the following: 1. uninstall VLC using Synaptic, then I also checked "Ubuntu Software" and removed it from there as well and last I deleted the /snap/vlc folder. I re-installed VLC using Synaptic and now everything works as it should. I guess VLC installation with snap is not so reliable.

Comment: Thanks I also had this same issue, and removing VLC from Ubuntu Software, then installing Synaptic Package Manager from Ubuntu Software, and using that to install vlc and vlc-bin packages (and their dependencies) fixed it for me.